# Complex numbers; complex exponents

Tags: complex-numbers

I have trouble doing this exercise:

Express $i$ in the form $re^{iθ}$
Hence find the exact value of $i^i$

so far I have $i=\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}+i\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Tkank you very much for any help!

Comment: Do you know that $e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)$?  

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: Your equation  $i=\cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}+\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ has several errors.  Compare it to the one in my previous comment.

Comment: $i = $ sum of two real numbers? !?!?!?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla That's what my "has several errors" referred to.  The OP's equation suggests that $i = 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post few times and I deleted one "i" next to sin by mistake. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$re^{i\theta} = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ by definition.

So $i = 0 + i = r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)$ where $r*\cos \theta = 0$ and $r*\sin \theta = 1$.  So $r = 1$ and $\theta = \frac {\pi} 2$.

So $i = e^{i\frac {\pi}2}$.

So $i^i = (e^{i\frac {\pi}2})^i = e^{i^2 \frac {\pi}2} = e^{-\frac {\pi}2}$ which is the real number $\sqrt {\frac 1{e^{\pi}}}$

Actually I over simplified.  $r = (-1)^k$ and $\theta = \frac {\pi} 2 + k\pi$ and $i^i = [(-1)^ke^{i(\pi/2 + k \pi}]^{i}= (-1)^{ki}e^{-\pi/2 - k \pi}$ which has multiple values.  One thing very different about complex exponents and logs is that the are multiple valued.

Answer (score 1):

Since $i=e^{i\pi/2}$

$$i^i=(e^{i\pi/2})^i=e^{i^2\pi/2}=e^{-\pi/2} \approx 0.20787957635$$

Comment: $i\equiv e^{5i\pi/2}$ also works fine.

Comment: @projectilemotion wouldn't this lead to multiple answers then?

Comment: @JaideepKhare. There is an underlying reason why Projectilemotion gave that comment. While your answer is technically correct, the reason of his comment can be found in an introductory course of complex analysis...Take that class when you are done with 12 grade. You won't regret!

Comment: Indeed, $i^i$ is a multivalued function. The result you obtained is the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value).

Comment: Similar to $\sqrt2$, it is just the principal solution to $x^2 = 2$ but $i^i$ is even more complicated.

Comment: @projectilemotion Oh! I didn't know that! I always thought $i^i$ to be $e^{-\pi/2} $

Comment: It is worth noting that the reason why Wolfram|Alpha returns $i^i=e^{-\pi/2}$ is because its default setting is to return the principal value.

Comment: This answer is technically correct ha ha.. +1